# How to extract a variable from function in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, user-defined-functions

I've written some code in Python2.7.3 and at some point I want a certain variable produced inside a function to be extracted and used later in my program. I have assigned the *global* definition on the variable but still no luck. Here is the code:

```
def target_fileopen():
     dirname = ' ' 
     dlg = wx.FileDialog(None, "Select file", dirname, "", "*.txt", wx.OPEN)
     if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
         filename = dlg.GetFilename()
         dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
         coordfile = open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'r')
         dlg.Destroy()

     global path
     path = str(dirname + "\\" + filename)
     return target_calc(coordfile)
     return(path)
print(path)
```

The error I get is that *global name 'path' is not defined*

This is just a sample, I don't really want to print the path in reality, just want it to place it as a static text in the GUI part of the application.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can't you make the function return that variable?

Comment: but you haven't called the function in the main body of the code... try print(target_fileopen()) instead of print(path)

Comment: The function is called by pressing a button.When the button is pressed the dialog appears. After I choose the file and press open in the dialog box I want the path to be printed. Actually I need it to take the StaticText's label argument--->text=wx.StaticText(win, label=path)

Comment: remove the line "global path" and then in the rest of you program call target_fileopen() instead of path as it returns path. So "text=wx.StaticText(win, label=target_fileopen())"

Comment: When I run it this way the filedialog appears immediately, not the gui

Answer (score 0):

It's OK on my computer.
I can access the global variable which defined in the function.
Do you invoke the method before you access the variable?

Comment: The method is called by pressing a button.When the button is pressed the dialog appears. After I choose the file and press open in the dialog box I want the path to be printed